# AWS CLI credentials in the Windows CMD terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, amazon-web-services

I found that if you use your AWS CLI programmatic keys in Linux, you can find them using

```
cat ~./aws/credentials
```

Later, you can remove them using

```
rm ~./aws/credentials
```

How can you do the same in the Windows CMD terminal? ***Or are they encrypted?***

I want to be sure that I have erased correctly my AWS CLI programmatic keys from my Windows CMD terminal.

Please see the image that is below.

***By the way, do not worry! Those are not my programmatic keys!***

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer in Reddit AWS!!! https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/

In Windows, using PowerShell as administrator, we need to use similar commands. However, we need to swap the dot and the slash.

This is the Windows solution:

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials
```

Finally,

```
rm ~/.aws/credentials
```